# javascript how to convert number 12 to float 12.00 (with 2 decimals), not string

Tags: javascript

is there a way to convert number 12 to float 12.00 (with 2 decimals), not a string.

background: so i have a angular input field.

```
<input 
                                        type="number" 
                                        step="0.01" 
                                        ng-model="data.amount">
```

let say amount from data feed is 12. i want to show it as 12.00 
so i need to turn 12 into 12.00 and assign it to data.amount.
that is why although 12 and 12.00 are the same, but i want it to display differently.

```
var a = 12;
a.toFixed(2); 
//returns "12.00" as string, i want it to return a number, because angular input type ="number" expect a number

parseFloat(a.toFixed(2)); parseFloat removes decimals.
```

any idea?

thanks!

Comment: The values `12` and `12.00` are precisely, exactly the same.

Comment: `a` is already of type number, which in Javascript is a floating point value. `12` is the same as `12.00`.

Comment: Did you try SIMD? var t = SIMD.Float32x4(12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0);
SIMD.Float32x4.extractLane(t, 0); extract lane should give float number

Comment: @Pointy i have updated my question to explain why i want 12.00 although they are same value.

Comment: If you're just interested in the display value, then `.toFixed()` should be no problem. The values of `<input>` fields are always strings anyway.

Comment: @Pointy, thanks. the input field has type="number", because user can update the number. and i want number key pad to displayed. .toFixed() returns string. angular throws error because it doesnt match the field type="number"

Comment: OK well I don't know what Angular is doing, but as far as the web browser is concerned the value of an `<input>` is a string regardless of the element "type" value.

Comment: @innek You can use a directive to achieve the same. I have given below a working sample.

Answer (score 3):

If this is about displaying the number as currency or the like, you need to use angular's formatting:

```
{{a | number:2}}
```

Comment: thanks, i have updated the question to include background. it is an input field. i dont think i can use formatting on input field.

Comment: @innek You can use a directive to achieve the same. I have given below a working sample.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to have a float notation in JavaScript, simply because there's no float type in it - all numeric types are simply: Number.

Since you only want to use it for displaying, you'll have to stick with the string notation (when you think of it, when you print a float on a screen, no matter the language, it becomes a string, especially when knowing how floats look like in memory, that's definitely not readable to humans, at least most of them :)).

I'm positive Angular won't complain whether you give it "12", 12, 12.00 or "12.00". If it's something you wrote, write a small converter function to use before passing the value to the problematic part of the script.

Comment: thanks for the input. I made the input field type="number" because it would bring up Number key pad in mobile. That field is for user to enter amount, so only numbers, decimal points are needed. if i use toFixed(2), it returns string. angular would throw error: Error: [ngModel:numfmt] Expected `12.00` to be a number

Comment: Don't use `toFixed` at all - give it a number (12 in this case). Only format it when you're displaying the value.

Answer (score 0):

As you can't use the `filter` with `ng-model`, you can use a `directive` to achieve the same as below.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('TestController', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    amount: 12
  };
});

app.directive('toFixed', ['$filter', function($filter){
   return {
     require: 'ngModel',
     link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {

      ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(data) {
        return $filter('number')(data, attrs.toFixed);
      });

      ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(data) {
        return $filter('number')(data, attrs.toFixed);
      });
     }
   };
}]);

angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="TestController">
<input 
                                        type="number" 
                                        step="0.01" 
                                        ng-model="data.amount" to-fixed="2">
</div>
```

Comment: I ran your snippet and I see '12', not '12.00'

Comment: I can see `12.00`. which browser have you used?

Comment: Firefox 43, that might be the issue...

Comment: yeah, I checked in chrome and looks good. will check in FF.

Comment: interesting. it works in chrome but not FF.

Comment: It is pure angular directive and filter. Nothing fancy other than this and should work there. I will check

Comment: @ppovoski It looks like a stack overflow snippet issue rather than angular issue. I have created a jsfiddle and can you give a try, `https://jsfiddle.net/balasuar/fprmb9cj/`. My FF is throwing some certificate issues and not opening both sites. I can check once I go home.

Comment: @Aruna, Your fiddle shows same thing, '12', not '12.00'.

Comment: Interesting. I will check this once I go home.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried the method of .toFixed after the Parsefloat like this:

var num = parseFloat(a).toFixed(2);